# Create Custom STS service in VS2012 with .net 4.5

Tags: wcf, wif

Since I'm new to WIF.
I want to create a custom STS on WIF, but these document only for .net 3.5:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748498.aspx
and I can't find these template in vs 2012.
So what should I do? Can anybody provide some information to me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The templates have been replaced with the [Identity and Access Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e).

Refer [Windows Identity Foundation in the .NET Framework 4.5 Beta: Tools, Samples, Claims Everywhere](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/03/15/windows-identity-foundation-in-the-net-framework-4-5-beta-tools-samples-claims-everywhere-2/)

There is no custom STS facility option anymore in the sense of a wizard as per FedUtil. As other posts allude to, you can still roll your own.

Refer: [What's New in Windows Identity Foundation 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873305.aspx).

Have a look at [Identity Server](http://thinktecture.github.com/) which is a very good custom STS and alter as required.

Comment: OP: _There is no custom STS facility option anymore_ - are you sure?  **Microsoft** says: _Build custom STSs. WIF makes it substantially easier to build a custom STS_ [Windows Identity Foundation 4.5 Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291066(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Writing a *custom STS service* is **still** available under WIF in .NET 4.5 or *WIF 4.5* for short.

> "*To create an STS you must derive from the **SecurityTokenService** class. In your custom class you must, at a minimum, override the **GetScope** and **GetOutputClaimsIdentity** methods...*", Microsoft [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.securitytokenservice(v=vs.110).aspx)

You start by deriving a new type from [System.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.securitytokenservice(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note that we now use the **SecurityTokenService** which is apart of .NET 4.5's **System.IdentityModel** and not the pre .NET 4.5 **Microsoft.IdentityModel**.

Please refer to the link below to see an example of a passive STS.

Microsoft's [Federation Metadata example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Federation-Metadata-34036040#content) is a reasonably complete example of custom STS.

MSDN:

> This sample will show you how to dynamically consume WS-Federation metadata at run time in an ASP.NET Web Application. You will also see **how to create a basic STS that produces WS-Federation metadata and issues tokens**.
>
> In addition this sample shows the basics of how claims have been integrated into the .NET framework. You will learn how a web application is enabled to use WIF. You will see how they are useful from within existing properties and functions, and how you can take the next step to using them directly using the ClaimsPrincipal class in System.Security.Claims. You also will also learn how to work with the local STS that is part of the Identity and Access tool for Visual Studio 2012. *[Tell me more](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Federation-Metadata-34036040#content)*

---

[1] [System.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.securitytokenservice(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Best answer and solution I could get on this question

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely new then writing a custom STS might not be such a good idea :-)  I would suggest having a look at the implementation given in ThinkTecture STS (https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2)  This is a sample STS that handles different tokens types (SAML, SWT and JWT) as well as different procotols (WSFederation, OAuth, ...)  There is too much in here for many simple cases but at least the code works.