# How To Implement Message Security in WCF using IssuedToken ClientCredentialType

Tags: c#, wcf, security

Well I'm new to WCF programming. Currently I have developed a WCF Service, and I need to implement Message Security using IssuedToken.

The service I have developed can be used by any client, but they need to get authenticated to the service using a token provided by an STS. **I can't use third party** solutions for an **STS** so I would like to create my own STS. Can anybody share some detailed information about it?

- How this can be implemented?
- How to create a custom STS and what changes would be made to the service and the client so as to use this STS for authentication?

Comment: _"How to create a custom STS"_ - See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598345/create-custom-sts-service-in-vs2012-with-net-4-5/21903489#21903489

Comment: is WIF included in .NET framework 3.5? Im restricted to use .NET Framework 3.5. Any workaround?

Comment: It's actually easier because the older versions had project wizards and templates that were removed in later versions.  e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517296.aspx

Comment: I've summarised these points into an answer below complete with a link regarding .NET 3.5 _WIF Visual Studio templates_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my [answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598345/create-custom-sts-service-in-vs2012-with-net-4-5/21903489#21903489), writing a custom STS service is still available under WIF in .NET 4.5 or WIF 4.5 for short:

As MSDN says:

> To create an STS you must derive from the SecurityTokenService class. In your custom class you must, at a minimum, override the GetScope and GetOutputClaimsIdentity methods...", Microsoft  [More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.securitytokenservice(v=vs.110).aspx)

[See original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598345/create-custom-sts-service-in-vs2012-with-net-4-5/21903489#21903489)

.NET 3.5 SP1 or .NET 4 users can use the *WIF Visual Studio templates* to easily generate a new STS

> In this scenario, you use the WIF Visual Studio templates and FedUtil to create an ASP.NET Web site that lets you access the current user’s claims through IClaimsPrincipal. The way this works is that FedUtil adds the ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule to your project. The module lets you convert the current user’s IPrincipal object to an IClaimsPrincipal object. [More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517296.aspx)

In the wizard below you would select **Create a new STS project in the current solution**.

[image]

Why they removed this little gem from later versions of WIF development is beyond me.